# App.Config key does not modifie

Tags: c#, app-config

I've tried these two methods that I found here on SatackOverFlow. Neither of these worked for me. Take a look at my code first:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
       KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

       settings.Remove("Valor1");
       settings.Add("Valor1", "NewValue");

       //save the file
       config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

       //reload the section you modified            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}
```

And:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

            //Update SaveBeforeExit
            settings["Valor1"].Value = "NewValue";

            //save the file
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

            //reload the section you modified
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}
```

**What do I want**
I want to change the values of my `App.Config` at runtime.

**Why do I want this?**
I'm working with RFID cards and I need to be able to change some configurations on runtime. These configurations may vary to each client?

**What's wrong ?**
Well, both methods, it DOES change the value at that time, but when I re-debug the application, the value is the same it was before the change.

Why? Is there something that I can do?

Even when I try to `REMOVE` and `ADD` a key, it still the same value. So I'm not able to delete a key programmatically?

Comment: Its so easy to click on the `DownVoteButton` could you at least say why ?

Comment: If you debug your app AGAIN the app.config is freshly copied from your project folder to bin/debug...

Comment: Every time you run the application from Visual Studio, it will copy your App.Config file to the bin folder, overwriting the changes your program made.

Comment: Are you certain your `app.config` isn't being overwritten by visual studio?

Comment: Thanks @rene . And there is no way to change it ? I mean, I want to just config it once, then everytime the client opens the application it will load the saved config...

Comment: Have you tried running the application from the `bin` folder and attaching the debugger? If your config file is changing because of recompiling then you should see the expected result when you attach the debugger.

Comment: @Guvante I guess it is. What I want to know if there is a way to REALLY change the value of app.config ? Or VS will always overwrite my changes? I thought when I remove/add or just change the value of the key on app.config it will change for good...

Comment: @Ghaleon that's how it will behave once the program is installed. However, when run from VS things are different. You can change the properties for `app.config` to `copy when newer`, and it should work for you in VS aswell.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen you mean at my `App.Config Properties` right ? and is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Ghaleon, I'm talking about a Visual Studio property for the file in your project called "Copy to output directory". It is not a bad practice as long as you understand what it does.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen yes, its a property of my App.Config file. I changed to "Copy if Newer". But still the same ;\
Guess there's no way to achieve ;\

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Setting instead of a app.config store? It will have an initial value but as soon as you saved a value it will retain/reload that value even across debug sessions.

In your app you can do

```
var s = new Settings();
s.Setting = "set to new value";
s.Save();
```

You add a setting from VS2010 form the properties window of your project by clicking the Settings tab on the left.

The settings file is used to generate a cs class withh [ApplicationSettingBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) as the base class.

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = 
        ((Settings)(ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(
        new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode()]
    [DefaultSettingValueAttribute("if no user setting is present")]
    public string Setting {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Setting"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Setting"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are succefully changing your config file, then your issue is that the application isn't cycling and pulling in the new config.  Can you kill your running instance and restart?

Comment: I tried the `Copy to output directory: Copy if Newer` but didn't worked. Gues there's no way to achieve that =P